# Simple Algebraic Problem: Help with Soccer Team Trip Problem (arithmetic)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

An easy one but I don't know whether the result is correct (decimals).

A soccer team wants to celebrate their victory and they decide to go on a trip.

- The team is made up of **20 students**
- The trip is **150$ per person**.
- The room is **50 dollars per night per person**.

They all have paid in total 7.350 dollars. **How many days** have they been on a trip?

*How I approached it*

Be it x for the days they've been on a trip. Days = x.

20 (150 + 50x) = 7350

20 * 150 + 20*50x = 7350

3000 + 1000x = 7350

1000x = 7350 - 3000

1000x = 4350

x = 4350/1000 = 4,35 days

My issue is with these decimals. You can't possibly express days in a decimal number. Do I just write the result like x = 4, ignoring the decimals or is there something wrong with the way I approached the problem?

Thanks a bunch

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the calculation, I get the same value you get.  I agree it doesn't make a lot of sense, as the hotel would, presumably, only charge full days.

Comment: Your math looks good to me too. I assume the problem comes from the fact that it is just a math problem and no one checked to make sure it made sense.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I think there's a typo.  If the number of students is 21, the answer comes out 4 nights.  (Which might mean the answer is 5 _days_)

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is fine.  As you say, the problem setter should have chosen values that result in a whole number of nights.